# Adobe Illustrator open a file in browser shortcut

Tags: google-chrome, browser, keyboard-shortcuts, adobe-illustrator

Is there a way I can have a shortcut to open a file I'm working on in an internet browser (specifically Chrome) from Adobe Illustrator?

Answer (score 1):

OK, here's one way of doing it with AppleScript. Paste the following into the AppleScript Editor and save it as "View SVG in Chrome.scpt" inside the /Applications/Adobe Illustrator/Presets/Scripts folder.

```
set tmpfile to "/tmp/ai-temp-" & ((random number) as string) & ".svg"
tell application "Adobe Illustrator"
    activate
    save the current document
    set openDoc to file path of current document as alias
    export current document to tmpfile as SVG
end tell
tell application "Google Chrome"
    activate
    open location "file://" & tmpfile
end tell
tell application "Adobe Illustrator"
    close current document
    open openDoc
end tell
```

Restart Illustrator and the script should appear in the <kbd>File</kbd>»<kbd>Scripts</kbd> menu.

A few caveats:

1. This works with Illustrator CS2, which is the most recent version I own. Things may have moved around a bit in later versions, although it should be possible to get this script working without too much trouble. I think scripting is a low priority at Adobe, so I wouldn't be surprised if nothing's changed at all.
2. The script saves the current file, exports the image to Chrome, and then reopens the file you were working on. This faffing about is unavoidable because Illustrator's AppleScript API doesn't allow you to save a copy of a file in a different location.
3. I'm assuming here that you want to export the file as an SVG image, but other formats are possible; just replace `SVG` in the above script with one of `Flash`, `GIF`, `JPEG`, `Photoshop`, `PNG24` or `PNG8`.
4. I'm not checking for errors, so unexpected things might happen if, for example, Illustrator doesn't have any files currently open when you run the script.